# Rails based DB, Google Maps user API, avoid layouts?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails-3, google-maps

I'm hoping for a little design guidance here.  I've got a Rails based DB application with lots of 'admin' screens written in the usual Rails ways including using a Rails layout.

But now I'm writing an 'end user' screen that is effectively some of the data represented on a full screen Google Maps map.  It does want a few knobs and settings so I will want I18n support but apart from that it seems like there is nothing to be gained from a Rails layout, or in fact most Rails infrastructure beyond the routes - or is there?

Anyone already stumbled down this path and able to share some thoughts on how best to approach this?  I've got a prototype working but still having nagging suspicions that my lack of experience in this arena means I might be missing some Rails goodness.

Answer (score 0):

What I ended up doing was creating two distinct layouts stylings, one for the admin side and one for the user side.  The key things to remember are:

- You need to tell Rails via initializers to process the additional layout
- You need to split the layout files into subdirectories otherwise Rails asset manager bundles everything into a single asset file
- You can make a similar split of any Javascript code that you might have written
- `stylesheet_link_tag` and `javascript_include_tag` in your files ensures that the correct layout styling and source code are brought into your file
- Use something like `render file: 'static_pages/map.html', layout: false` in your controller to ensure that the default layout is not wrapped around any files that might not want it (and are typically standalone HTML)

I'm sure there are other patterns that might achieve the same effect but this has worked for the simplistic requirements that I had.